# How can I SetOpenAction so that the pdf uses default zoom type?

Tags: itext

I am trying to set the zoom type of a PDF to Default so that when I open it in Acrobat it will use the default zoom that you can set in preferences based on each user. I have tried `stamper.Writer.SetOpenAction((PdfAction)null);` but this only works when the default zoom is a percentage (like 1200%). If I set the default zoom in Acrobat to fit width or fit page it always opens the PDF in 100%. Can anyone show me what I need to do to make fit page and fit width defaults work on a processed pdf?

FYI: I get the same incorrect result with:

```
    PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, new PdfDestination(""), stamper.Writer);
    stamper.Writer.SetOpenAction(action);
```

Comment: Are you trying to set DOCVIEW setting in already exist PDF file or in New Pdf creating using iTextSharp?